# Working with a dataset on firebase sending via python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was testing a dataset I have on Firebase.

[image: Firebase Snapshot]
Using the this instruction

```
 result = firebase.get('/Lot',"I") #THIS PULLS THE DATASET FROM FIREBASE
```

When I use the the firebase.get instruction in python I get the following.

```
runfile('C:/Users/Maint.Tech/parking_app/firebase_test.py', 
wdir='C:/Users/Maint.Tech/parking_app')
[None, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

1. *What is "None"?*  When I manipulate the numbers after "none" everything reflects in dataset correctly.
2. From python I am trying to take a array in python and send this via json list. *How would I set up python array to reflect the correct structure to send to firebase?* This is the instruction I have sent that updates the dataset correctly.  Just need to figure out how to write the python right..

`send_data = firebase.put('/Lot','I',[None, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0])`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase doesn't natively store arrays. When you send it an array, it stores the items from that array in number properties instead.

So if you store the follow array in JavaScript:

```
ref.set([ first, second, third ]);
```

Firebase actually stores it as:

```
{
  "0": "first",
  "1": "second",
  "2": "third"
}
```

Now if you remove the first item from the database, and read the result back into an array in JavaScript, you get:

```
[ undefined, "second", "third" ]
```

And that last one seems very close to what you have in your Python script.

But in this case that's all just background information. It looks like you're actually sending the `None` yourself in the `put` to Firebase. If you don't want `None` in there, don't send it, and instead do:

```
send_data = firebase.put('/Lot','I',[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0])
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did not even think.. "Try taking it out."  I took it out an sure enough it updated fine.